# Passing a variable between Python functions

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to Python and coding and am trying to figure out how to pass the result of one function to a calling function so that the variable passed can be used within the calling function.

In the code below, I get an error that states that:

> global name 'quiz' is not defined.

My intent is to pass back a string to be printed based upon user input.

```
difficulty = raw_input("Please enter the level of difficulty: easy, medium, or hard: ")

def test_method(difficulty):
  if difficulty == 'easy':
    quiz = "Yup - quiz me"
  else:
    quiz = "Nope - yikes!"
  return quiz
```

I've tried using `print quiz` here and the expected string prints. But what I would really like to do is pass back the quiz variable to the calling function and then print the result from there.

```
def test_call(difficulty):
  test_method(difficulty)
  print quiz

test_call(difficulty)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign and / or return quiz

```
def test_call(difficulty):
    quiz = test_method(difficulty)
    print quiz
    return quiz
```

Comment: Thank you BenJ!  That did the trick - your help is much appreciated!

Comment: @Aaron Glad I could help!